# Is eval Dangerous in Django

Tags: django, forms

Is there a better way to make a reusable create method? I am using `eval` which is considered dangerous, but I do not think it is the way it is used here as I am just substituting a string for the form value.

```
def convert_camel_case_to_underscore(model_name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', model_name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()

@login_required
def create(request, model, template_name='create.html'):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.get_profile()

    if profile.county_state:
        county_state = profile.county_state
    else:
        county_state = get_object_or_404(CountyState, id=1)

    model_name = model._meta.object_name
    model_goto = convert_camel_case_to_underscore(model_name)
    model_lower = convert_camel_case_to_underscore(model_name)
    form_name = model_name + "Form"

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = eval(form_name)(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_lower = form.save(commit=False)
            model_lower.county_state = county_state
            model_lower.user = request.user 
            model_lower.created_by = request.user.username
            model_lower.last_modified_by = request.user.username
            model_lower.save()
            url = '/parcels/%s/show/%s' % (model_goto, str(model_lower.id))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            error = "form is not valid"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/errors/index/')
    else:
        form = eval(form_name)()
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: To add to my post, I want to create a much as possible reusable create method. I am using ModelForms and am sending the Model with the urls. It works, I am just wondering if it is dangerous. If its not dangerous, then feel free to use it. model_name = is the Name of the Model submitted, model_goto is for the success_url which is a show for me. model_lower is the lowercase model for the form to change. You cannot use model_lower in the success_url as it will evaluate into a Model object after the model_lower form business.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to put the common logic of the form classes in a super class's create method so that you don't eval?

Answer (score 4):

It is not dangerous in this specific case, if you are absolutely sure you completely control what is `model`.

However, I think it is better to avoir using `eval` when not needed, you can do something like this:

```
import models

# Get the name of the class of the model object
model_name = model.__class__.__name__

# Get the class model_name + "Form" from the 'models' module
formklass = getattr(models, model_name + "Form")

# Instantiate the class
form = formklass()
```

Comment: This approach also makes it more clear where your objects are coming from. You probably have an import to ensure `eval(form_name)` executes successfully but an IDE will likely identify that import as unused so you have to remember why it's there when you're making updates in 6 months.

Comment: When I use the model_name I get ModelBase as the return value and not Zoning which has a super class of ModelBase through models.Model. I looked in the djang oModelBase code and they use _meta. on the __class__, would I need to ask for something like __subclass__ ?? Also, using formklass I get an error of Zoning has no attribute ZoningForm. Do I need to add a form to my model? Thanks for the rapid answer.

Comment: I also added model_app = model._meta.app_label to get the app name for the success_url show, so parcels is replaces by %s and then substituted by str(model_app)

Comment: I guess Zoning is the name of your model. Are you sure the object `model` is an instance of Zoning in your test? You can see this by simply printing the object. Yes, you need to define a <model>Form class for each <model> that can be given to your create function.